# Dropdown menu doesn't work on mobile

Tags: android, jquery, html, ios, css

I have a simple dropdown menu and having trouble making it work on mobile devices.
It works fine on desktop, when I hover it slides down the menu and when I mouse out it hides, however in IOS or android when I tap on menu item it shows the sub menu, but it just stays that way even if I tap on the parent item again.

Ideally it should: tap open menu, tap again on the parent item - to close menu.

html:

```
<ul class="acc-menu">
  <li class="parent">
    <a href="#"><span>Account</span></a>
    <ul>
      <li class=""><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
.acc-menu {
  margin-top: -6px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.parent span {
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.acc-menu li {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 500;
  margin: 0 1px;
}

.acc-menu li a {
  display: block;
  line-height: 18px;
  color: #333;
  text-align: left;
}

.acc-menu ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -14px;
  display: none;
  margin: 0 0 0 -1px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-indent: 10px;
}

.acc-menu ul li {
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
}

.acc-menu ul a {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 5px;
}

.acc-menu ul a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

jq:

```
jQuery('.acc-menu li').hover(
  function() {
    jQuery('ul', this).stop().slideDown(100);
  },
  function() {
    jQuery('ul', this).stop().slideUp(100);
  }
);
```

[Here is the codepen link](http://codepen.io/lvekua/pen/EZNQea)

Comment: Try adding focus, besides hover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hover doesn't play nice on mobile. You could try adding a `click` listener with a `toggleClass()` event for mobile and leave the conventional hover on desktop:

- Add `.display` class to your CSS with `display: block;`
- Attach `.on("click")` listener with `toggleClass("display");` on `ul` **only** if viewport width is equal or below `414px` (feel free to adjust viewport width value to your benefit).

**EDIT (comment based):**

- Set `:hover` through @media query only for desktop, and left click listener for mobile via jQuery.

[Test it resizing viewport here. First resize it, then run the code and try to either hover or click.(UPDATED)](https://jsfiddle.net/Syden/Lsvwyx0c/3/)

```js
var viewport = $(window).width();
if (viewport <= 414) {
  jQuery('.acc-menu').on("click", function() {
    jQuery('ul').toggleClass("display");
  });
}
```

```css
.acc-menu {
  margin-top: -6px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.parent span {
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}
.acc-menu li {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 500;
  margin: 0 1px;
}
.acc-menu li a {
  display: block;
  line-height: 18px;
  color: #333;
  text-align: left;
}
.acc-menu ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -14px;
  display: none;
  margin: 0 0 0 -1px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-indent: 10px;
}
.acc-menu ul.display {
  display: block;
}
.acc-menu ul li {
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
}
.acc-menu ul a {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 5px;
}
.acc-menu ul a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
@media (min-width: 415px) {
    .acc-menu li:hover ul {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="acc-menu">
  <li class="parent">
    <a href="#"><span>Account</span></a>
    <ul>
      <li class=""><a href="#">Link 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class=""><a href="#">Link 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class=""><a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </li>
      <li class=""><a href="#">Link 4</a>
      </li>
      <li class=""><a href="#">Link 5</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: this works fine on both mobile and desktop, however there is a little problem with hover event on desktop: in DOM style="display: none" becomes to - display: none; height: 177px; padding-top: 0px; margin-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; and stays there, which is causing submenues to be invisibele; is there any solution to this?

Comment: Like a charm! Thanks a million @Syden

Answer (score -1):

You can do this purely with CSS using `:hover`.

```css
.acc-menu {
  margin-top: -6px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.parent span {
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.acc-menu li {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 500;
  margin: 0 1px;
}

.acc-menu li a {
  display: block;
  line-height: 18px;
  color: #333;
  text-align: left;
}

.acc-menu ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -14px;
  display: none;
  margin: 0 0 0 -1px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-indent: 10px;
}

.acc-menu ul li {
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
}

.acc-menu ul a {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 5px;
}

.acc-menu ul a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="acc-menu">
  <li class="parent">
    <a href="#"><span>Account</span></a>
    <ul>
      <li class=""><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you simply add a click event besides the hover one

```
jQuery('.acc-menu li').on('click',
  function() {
    jQuery('ul', this).stop().slideToggle(100);
  }
);
```

[Pen](http://codepen.io/rema/pen/bgBvxX)